# Include syntax on MASM32

Tags: assembly, include, x86, environment-variables, masm32

When including files into MASM32, it cannot find it's own files. After including masm32rt.inc, the assembler cannot find \masm32\include\windows.inc

Apparently most MASM system include files begin with \ instead of specyfing a relative or absolute path.

I tried specifying the directory in %PATH%, setting the /I compile switch, and setting the INCLUDE and MASM32 environment variables without success.

It seems that it is giving windows a path it doesn't understand. A solution would be to do a mass find and replace in files, and add C: before the directives. However I would like to prevent editing the files they provide, and find out the proper way to do it.

How do I set it up so that it can find it's own files?

Answer (score 2):

You could deal with this in two ways that I know of, you need to check your MASM32 documentation, there's an `-I` command switch to specify the include directory, or use an environment variable (`MASM32` or `INCLUDE` IIRC)..You can set the environment variable by right-clicking on 'My Computer', left-click on 'Properties', a dialog box with different tab pages appears, left-click on 'Advanced', then left-click on 'Environment Variables', and stick in the environment variables for 'INCLUDE' and 'MASM32'...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be designed to require development on the same drive that it's installed on.  In my case I installed it to F:, but my dev stuff is on C:...  I ended up copying it from F: to C: (and leaving in both places) so that it can find it no matter what.